# Pregunta básica de Python que no logro resolver

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo programación y quiero hacer una pequeña aplicación en la cual cuando añada un ticket, llamando a un API de Quandl saca los valores que necesito en una tabla, el valor se le añade a traves de "campo", el caso es que me está dando error de invalid syntax cuando compilo en def addgrafbolsa, que estoy haciendo mal? Un cordial saludo:S

Pongo el código en concreto abajo:

```
class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        #Definimos la ventana y las pestañas
        self.title("Titulo principal de la ventana")
        self.minsize(640, 400)
        self.configure(background = '#4D4D4D')
        controlpestanas = ttk.Notebook(self)
        controlpestanas.pack(expan = 1, fill = "both")

        self.pestana1 = ttk.Frame(controlpestanas)
        controlpestanas.add(self.pestana1, text ="Pestaña 1")

        self.pestana2 = ttk.Frame(controlpestanas)
        controlpestanas.add(self.pestana2, text ="Pestaña 2")

        self.pestana3 = ttk.Frame(controlpestanas)
        controlpestanas.add(self.pestana3, text ="Pestaña 3")
        self.addfunciones() #llamamos a la funcion addfunciones que añade los valores en la pestaña
        campo.addgrafbolsa() # Llamamos a la función de muestra los parametros de la bolsa

    #Función en la que se añade funciones a las pestañas    
    def addfunciones(self):
        etiqueta1 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pestana1, text = "primera etiqueta")
        etiqueta1.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 8, pady = 10)

        subetiqueta = ttk.Label(etiqueta1, text = "Introduce ticket del valor")
        subetiqueta.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = "W")
        campo = Entry(etiqueta1, width=20)
        campo.grid(column=1, row=0)

    def addgrafbolsa(campo)
        mostrar_valor = quandl.get_table('ZACKS/FR', paginate=True, ticker=[campo], per_end_date={'gte': '2010-01-01'}, qopts={'columns':['ticker','per_end_date', 'ebitda_margin', 'ret_equity', 'asset_turn']})
        mostrar_valor = ttk.Label(etiqueta1)
        mostrar_valor.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = "W")

def posicionar_etiquetas(self):
    label1 = Label(self, text = "posicion 1")
    label2 = Label(self, text = "posicion 2")
    label1.place(x = 20, y = 30)
    label2.place(x = 50, y = 30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Root()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Parece que se te ha olvidado poner dos puntos tras la cabecera de la función. Por otro lado revisa la indentación de `posicionar_etiquetas()`, que se ve fuera de la clase y debería estar dentro

Comment: Gracias, parece ser que este era el problema, gracias !!

Comment: Recomiendo que uses algún IDE como Pycharm para que te vaya diciendo donde falla tu código.